# ¿Qué significado o propósito tiene el '.' (punto) en programación?

Tags: javascript, poo

Quisiera entender un poco mas acerca de la puntuación en programación para poder comprender mejor el código. Quisiera saber que función cumple el punto y que nombre tiene en programación, quisiera saber esto con le objetivo de aprender mas.

Ejemplo:

```js
var variable = 'Hola mundo';

variable = variable.replace(/\s/g,'_');
console.log(variable);
```

Para entender un poco mejor a lo que me refiero. Que objetivo tiene el punto que conecta console con el log() `console.log()` o en otro ejemplo como `variable.replace()`

Comment: No entiendo, te refieres al punto que concatena `console` con `log` ??

Comment: Tu pregunta no es para nada clara, intenta orientarnos mejor

Comment: ¿A qué punto te refieres amigo?

Comment: Ya edité la pregunta, me refiero exactamente al punto que conecta el console con el log() como se muestra ahora en la pregunta, mis disculpas por no aclarar correctamente a que me refería

Comment: Creo que el se refiere a los métodos de console y los métodos del prototipo string, básicamente esta preguntado por poo

Comment: Con el punto accedes a un miembro del objeto, ya sea variable o función.

Comment: Es decir que console es un objeto y dentro del objeto console puede acceder a una función llamada log() ¿cierto?

Comment: Si. a esa función se le denomina método del objeto (en este caso el objeto es console), y en los datos primitivos (string, boolean, object, etc) en JavaScript utilizan prototipos que básicamente es un objeto que pueden acceder solo esos datos primitivos. en tu ejemplo cuando utilizas variable.replace variable es un string, por lo que ese string puede acceder al método replace del prototipo string, por eso es que el valor 'Hola mundo' tiene métodos por que en realidad estas accediendo a los métodos del prototipo string en este caso el método seria replace

Comment: Si queres profundizar mucho en esto de los prototipos puedes ver este enlace https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Object_prototypes pero con que entiendas lo que acabe de escribir es mas que suficiente.

Comment: Y aquí ahí un enlace de los todos métodos del prototipo string https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String#M%C3%A9todos_de_instancia puedes acceder a estos métodos desde cualquier string por ejemplo "Hola mundo".charAt(3), también te recomiendo que si no sabes programación orientada a objetos, veas un video en youtube para entenderlo mejor, que es un objeto como crearlos como crear sus métodos etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por lo general el "punto" al que te refieres, en programación en general, quiere decir que quieres acceder a "algo" que se encuentra en un nivel inferior.
Por seguir tu ejemplo:

```
console.log() //console es un objeto y log() es un método que contiene el objeto console
```

lo mismo con `variable.replace()` variable es el objeto y replace es un método que incluye este objeto.

Pasa lo mismo con los atributos de las clases:

```
Objeto.contador //Objeto es un objeto y contador es un atributo de este mismo
```

Te pongo un ejemplo algo más extenso:

```
class Rectangulo {
  constructor (alto, ancho) {
    this.alto = alto;
    this.ancho = ancho;
  }
  // Getter
  get area() {
     return this.calcArea();
   }
  // Método
  calcArea () {
    return this.alto * this.ancho;
  }
}

const cuadrado = new Rectangulo(10, 10);

//cuadrado.area nos devolverá un número
//el .area se refiere al atributo "area" de la clase Rectangulo
console.log(cuadrado.area); // 100
```

> https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Classes#M%C3%A9todos_prototipo

Esto es así en la gran mayoría de lenguajes de programación orientados a objetos salvo unos pocos (PHP...) donde se utilizan otras puntuaciones para acceder a sus atributos internos

Espero haberte aclarado algo tus dudas

Answer (score 0):

En los lenguajes de programación, Se manejan varios tipos de filosofías, una de las demás populares es la programación orienta a objetos, en esta se maneja clases y métodos.

El punto se podría decir que es un delimitador que permite acceder a los atributos de una clase. En JavaScript se tiene la filosofía que todo son objetos, se podría especificar como una clase que tiene atributos y métodos. En el ejemplo que das, especifica que el objeto `console` tiene una función llamada `log`, este permite acceder a la funcion por medio del punto, en este caso se manejaría de la siguiente forma

```
console.log("hola mundo");
```

Hay que aclarar que no todos los lenguajes funcionan de la misma manera, en php se pueden acceder a la funciones de una clase por medio de flechas `->` de la siguiente forma, teniendo una clase Hola que cuenta con una función mundo, se accedería de la siguiente forma

```
$hola = new Hola(); // aquí especifico que la variable $hola, contendrá la instancia de la clase Hola 
$hola->mundo(); // por ende la variable $hola puede acceder a las funciones de la clase Hola
```

Answer (score 0):

En ese caso que citas en particular, el punto sirve para acceder a un método de una clase que no es más que la llamada de una función como parámetro en un objeto.

Por ende, en la programación orientada a objetos el punto sirve (no solo) para acceder a los métodos o propiedades de un objeto.

Ejemplo si el objeto casa tiene una propiedad color de valor rojo y un método alarma() que es una función que dispara la alarma:

```
casa.color # Devuelve el color del objeto casa

casa.alarma() # Ejecuta la alarma del objeto casa
```

Esto puede variar dependiendo del lenguaje que utilices pero en los lenguajes orientados a objetos suelen haber similitudes en este tipo de conceptos.